# Echo value of checkbox checked element in HTML form

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I've created an HTML form that has checkboxes that are checked dynamically due to a variable from a previous page (there is only one checkbox checked each time).

What I'd like is to echo the value of this checkbox out (to make the main title of the page so javascript alert is not adapted).

Example :

```
<html>
    <body>
    <h1>Here I'd like to echo the value of the checkbox that is checked<h1>
    <form id="myform" name="myform">
       <p>
       <input type="checkbox" name="car" id="porsche" /> <label for="porsche">porsche</label><br />
       <input type="checkbox" name="car" id="ferrari" /> <label for="ferrari">ferrari</label><br />
       </p>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function loopForm(form,car) {
       var cbResults = 'Checkboxes: ';
       var radioResults = 'Radio buttons: ';
       for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++ ) {
          if (form.elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
             if (form.elements[i].id == car) {
                 form.elements[i].checked = true ;
             }
          }
        }
     }
     ...
     // This function will check one of the two checkboxes
     loopForm(document.myform,car);
     </script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: echo out where? I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: @Rijk van Wel Echo it on the page.

Comment: It's always nice to be downvoted without knowing why.

Comment: I don't get it. *What* do you want to output *where*? What does "to make the main title of the page" mean and what javascript alert are you talking about?

Comment: @Sebastian Wramba I've edited my post to put an example.

Comment: "Echo" is a confusing word to use since JS doesn't have such concept. Did I understand correctly that you want to change the text inside the `<h1>` tag to match the label of a checked checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I can do, I'm afraid, is the following:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var checkboxes = [];

for (i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
    if (inputs[i].type == 'checkbox' && inputs[i].getAttribute('checked') == 'checked'){
        checkboxes.push(inputs[i].value);
    }
}

document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = checkboxes;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XUMhG/).

This is slightly clunky, but does, at least, use plain JavaScript; albeit it does seem to require that the checked checkboxes be marked up as following: `checked="checked"`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery to achieve this. Listen for the [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change) event on the checkboxes and change the [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text) of the h1 when this happens.